# What is the input format for 3D data for LIBSVM?

Tags: math, input, libsvm

I have a data set with accelerometer sequences. The sensor outputs samples at 30 hertz for 2 seconds, hence i got sequences of length 60. Each sample has an x, y and z value. Thus a sequence looks like this:

```
1: (2.5, 2.1, 1.5) 2:(3.1, 4.2, 7.5) ..... 60: (2.1, 4.5, 9.3)
```

when i run LibSVM's checkdata.py i get the following error:

```
line 2: feature '1:(-6.7965198,6.5,6.5)' not an <index>:<value> pair, <index> integer, <value> real number
```

How should I format 3 dimensional data?

EDIT: the range for all directions = -10 to 10

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand your other question... since your sequences are of fixed length, you could concatenate them into a single data point of length 180, e.g. :

1: x_1 2: y_1 3:z_1 4:x_2 5:y_2 6:z_2 ..... 178:x_60 179:y_60 180:z_60

Comment: ok i understand that, but wouldnt that affect pattern recognition rates?
I'll give it a go anyway thank you!